# Using CSS to show a background image and it's not working

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to use a image as a link and use CSS to show that image, however it's not working and not showing the image at all.

HTML

```
<a id="nav_a_img" href="#"></a>
```

CSS

```
#nav_a_img{
 background: url("image/nav/home.png") no-repeat;
 width: 32px;
 height: 32px;

}

#nav_a_img:hover{
 background: url("image/nav/home_w.png") no-repeat;
 width: 32px;
 height: 32px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#nav_a_img{
 background: url("image/nav/home.png") no-repeat;
 display:block; /*<=== add this*/
 width: 32px;
 height: 32px;
 }
```

FA008

Answer (score 0):

`width` and `height` do by definition not work on elements that have `display:inline`, which is the default for `a` elements.

Use `display:inline-block` or `display:block`, or float the link (depending on what exactly you want to achieve here).

Answer (score 0):

Why not....

```
<a href="#"><div id="nav_a_img"></div></a>


#nav_a_img{
    background: url("image/nav/home.png") no-repeat;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
}
#nav_a_img:hover{
    background: url("image/nav/home_w.png") no-repeat;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
}
```

Comment: That was tried as well, just not getting why it's not even showing the image as it should be.

Comment: Are you sure the URL for the image is correct? Typically it's "/images/etc", not "/image/etc".

Comment: It was due to display: block; was needed in the CSS